# L.heatLayer is not a function

Tags: javascript, laravel, leaflet, heatmap

I have 2 scripts,

First one is .html file. Heat layer is worked.

```
<html>
  <!-- See also: http://kempe.net/blog/2014/06/14/leaflet-pan-zoom-image.html -->
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css">
    <style>
    #image-map {
      width: 100%;
      height: 600px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="image-map"></div>

    <!-- <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script> -->

    <script src='leaflet.js'></script>
    <script src="leaflet-heat.js"></script>


    <script>
    // Using leaflet.js to pan and zoom a big image.
    // See also: http://kempe.net/blog/2014/06/14/leaflet-pan-zoom-image.html


var addressPoints = [

    [0, 0, "1"],
    [0, 0, "1"],
    [0, 0, "1"],
    [0, 0, "1"],
    [0, 0, "1"],
    [0, 0, "1"],
    [0, 0, "1"],
    [0, 0, "1"],
    [0, 0, "1"],
    [0, 0, "1"],

    [-60, 170, "1"],
    [-60, 170, "1"],
    [-60, 170, "1"],
    [-60, 170, "1"],
    [-60, 170, "1"],
    [-60, 170, "1"],
    [-60, 170, "1"],
    [-60, 170, "1"],
    [-60, 170, "1"],
    [-60, 170, "1"],
    
];




    // create the slippy map
    var map = L.map('image-map', {
      minZoom: 1,
      maxZoom: 4,
      center: [0, 0],
      zoom: 2,
      crs: L.CRS.Simple
    });

    // dimensions of the image
    var w = 2093,
        h = 925,
        url = 'Tower_A_1st_floor.jpg';

    // calculate the edges of the image, in coordinate space
    var southWest = map.unproject([0, h], map.getMaxZoom()-1);
    var northEast = map.unproject([w, 0], map.getMaxZoom()-1);
    var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

    // add the image overlay, 
    // so that it covers the entire map
    L.imageOverlay(url, bounds).addTo(map);
    var heat = L.heatLayer(addressPoints).addTo(map);

    // tell leaflet that the map is exactly as big as the image
    map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

But the 2nd one, I'm trying to integrated with blade laravel template. This is the code

```
@extends('template')

@section('title', 'Heatmap')

@section('head')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('ElaAdmin/assets/css/leaflet/leaflet.css')}}">

    <style>
        #image-map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div id="image-map"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('ElaAdmin/assets/js/leaflet/leaflet-heat.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('ElaAdmin/assets/js/leaflet/leaflet.js') }}"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var addressPoints = [
            [-60, 170, "1"],
            [-60, 170, "1"],
            [-60, 170, "1"],
            [-60, 170, "1"],
            [-60, 170, "1"],
            [-60, 170, "1"],
            [-60, 170, "1"],
            [-60, 170, "1"],
            [-60, 170, "1"],
            [-60, 170, "1"],

        ];

        // create the slippy map
        var map = L.map('image-map', {
            minZoom: 1,
            maxZoom: 4,
            center: [-58, 133],
            zoom: 2,
            crs: L.CRS.Simple
        });

        // dimensions of the image
        var w = 2093,
            h = 925,
            url = "{{ asset('ElaAdmin/images/Tower A 1st floor.jpg')}}";

        // calculate the edges of the image, in coordinate space
        var southWest = map.unproject([0, h], map.getMaxZoom()-1);
        var northEast = map.unproject([w, 0], map.getMaxZoom()-1);
        var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

        // add the image overlay, 
        // so that it covers the entire map
        L.imageOverlay(url, bounds).addTo(map);
        var heat = L.heatLayer(addressPoints).addTo(map);

        // tell leaflet that the map is exactly as big as the image
        map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
    </script>
    
@endsection
```

My question is why the heatmap not show on script #2 even though worked on script #1.

The error message are

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined

Uncaught TypeError: L.heatLayer is not a function
```

Im sure file load correctly, but why L.heatLayer is not a function?

Any help will be appreciate

Comment: Load `leaflet.js` first, and `leaflet-heat.js` second.